# Bracha on Mechiat Amalek

Tags: blessing, prayer-book, amalek

Is there a bracha to be made over killing Amalekites? If so, what is the nusach of this bracha?

Comment: @יהושעק https://matzav.com/rav-gustman-i-fulfilled-the-mitzvah-of-mechiyas-zecher-amalek-with-my-bare-hands/

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky Zatzal in Taama Dikra end of Esther writes that most likely that when Mordechai hung Haman he made a Bracha Al Mitzvas Mechias Amalek.